# Why does my http request not return a response

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, router

I have several routes in my api that work perfectly but while trying to implement a comment system I dont receive any response either from going to the url (node backend) or from postman.

My server JS is as follows and works for post, teams, users, but it does not work for comments.

Server.js File Below:

```
    //load server
const express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const multer = require('multer');

//db

const db = require('./config/db');

  db
  .authenticate()
  .then(() => {
    console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
  });

//image upload 
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'public')
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    let date = new Date(Date.now());

    cb(null, date.getDay() + '-' + date.getDate() + '-' + file.originalname )
  }
})

var upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file')

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}))
app.use(cors());
app.use(express.static('./public'))
app.use(morgan('combined'));

const router = require('./routes/user.js')
const postRoute = require('./routes/post.js');

app.use('/posts', require('./routes/post.js'));
app.use('/teams', require('./routes/teams.js'));
app.use('/comments', require('./routes/comments.js'));



app.use(router)


app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${port}`));
```

Below are my comment api routes:

```
const express =require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('../config/db');
const Comments = require('../models/Comments');
// const connection = getConnection()
const router = express.Router();
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

router.get('/', (req, res) => 
Comments.findAll().then( comments => {
    console.log(comments);
    res.json(comments);
    // res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)));


router.get('/:id', (req, res) => 
Comments.findAll({
    where: {
        postId: req.params.id
    }
}).then( comments => {
    console.log(comments);
    res.json(comments);
    // res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)));



router.post('/add/:id', (req, res) => {

    Comments.create(req.body).then(comments => {
        console.log(req.body)
        res.json(comments);
        console.log(comments)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
});


module.exports = router;
```

Im posting my Teams Api Route To Show what i have that has been working perfectly for me:

```
    //will contain all user routes
const express =require('express');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const db = require('../config/db');
const Teams = require('../models/Teams');
// const connection = getConnection()
const router = express.Router()
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');



//find all teams
router.get('/', (req, res) => 
Teams.findAll().then( team => {
    console.log(team);
    res.json(team);
    // res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)));


//find Team  by ID
router.get('/:id', (req, res) => 
Teams.findAll({
    where: {
        id: req.params.id
    }
}).then( team => {
    console.log(team);
    res.json(team);
    // res.sendStatus(200);
})
.catch(err => console.log(err)));

//add users image 



module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because It was expecting a request, and i wasnt giving it one. Have to just return response.

```
router.get('/').then(res => {
Comments.findAll().then(comments => {
    console.log(comments);
    res.json(comments.data);
})
})
```